# How to run TestFlight build locally

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight

We're beta testing right now and users are experiencing crashes when they select a cell in the explore page. `didSelect` is suppose to push the users to another view controller that will display posts.

When I run the app locally on Xcode everything is fine, no crashes. I sent myself an invite and installed the testflight build and sure enough the app crashes when I select a category on the explore page. Is it possible to run the TestFlight build on Xcode so I can see why its crashing? I thought the builds was the same but there must be a difference between TestFlight and running it locally on Xcode.

Here is the pushing code

```swift
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "selectedDiscoverCell") as! DiscoverPostsViewController
        vc.discoverCategories = discoverCategories[indexPath.row]
        vc.styleDetails = styleDetails[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)


    }
```

No errors, when I run a break on each line it works as expected..

Comment: You should be able to get the crash report from TestFlight - When the app crashes the device should prompt you to report the crash.  My suspicion would be that `vc!` in the `pushViewController`.  Everything before that is conditionally unwrapped.  A better pattern is probably `if let vc = storyboard ...` and perhaps show an alert if that if fails at least while you are testing.

Comment: Yeah the crash report doesn't really help much it doesn't tell me much about the actual crash. And Okay thanks I'll go ahead and change that.

Comment: If you symbolicate the crash log you should have the line on which the crash occurred.  You should also get an exception message

Comment: Thanks for educating me on that. Still new to testlfight. I'll do that too!

Comment: @Paulw11 Any reason why crash logs won't show up in the Organizer?

Comment: TestFlight crashes don't show up in the organiser.  They show up in App Store Connect in the TestFlight section.

Comment: Oh all I get is crash feedback in the crash section. That is the section you're talking about correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200986/discussion-between-paulw11-and-clint).

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry mate, that's misleading. Crashes defo show up in Organizer, IF the user has checked 'submit data to developers' under settings.

Comment: @Clint the code you posted is not safe. Firstly, you do not check whether `discoverCategories` and `styleDetails` have enough data to access with the row index. Secondly, you did not check whether the `vc` was even instantiated and just bang. I would add safe checks around these three things with `print` statements -> then attach console app on your mac to your device and run the build from testflight.

Comment: @zaitsman Hey thanks! I'm fixing that code now. I appreciate it! Hopefully it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your TestFlight build locally, first consider whether this is really what you want - vs. debugging the equivalent build.  So find out what you're actually sending to TestFlight.  It's what you're archiving.  So look at your scheme's settings - select Archive section of its settings, and see what configuration of your target you're archiving.

Once you know your archive's project configuration, edit that configuration temporarily in the target's Build Settings to allow for debugging (such as turning off optimization, not stripping debug symbols, etc... just walk through the target's build settings and compare your debug configuration vs. whatever configuration you use when archiving (typically it's Release but you might have a custom configuration).

Alternatively, if you just want to run (without debugging) the archive build, just temporarily change your scheme's Run setting "Build Configuration" to whatever configuration you use for archiving - then run the app.

If you still can't repro the crash, then revert all the temporary changes I suggested above and try archiving as normal - only instead of sending to Connect, choose to create an .ipa.  You can drop it into iTunes to install it onto the connected device (or so I've heard).  Then you can at least verify the crash.  Maybe you can then "attach" to the running process prior to crashing... maybe...

Comment: Unfortunately changing the scheme settings didn't reproduce the crash.I also turned off optimization and it still crashes. I'll go through  the targets build settings again and compare but If I remember correctly I believe it is the same as run

Comment: I'll try not stripping the symbols this time when submitting

Comment: This helped, thank you. Just had to play around the configur